# Add page title as body class on page load

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to jQuery and javascript.  I am trying to

1. get the page title when the page is loaded and
2. assign that page title to the body tag.

I am trying to load a different background image and color for each page.  I have been successful using css for the page backgrounds but the background stops at the bottom of my footer. The body tag is controlling the background below my footer and since each page has a different background, I need the body to pick up the background-color of the loaded page.

Answer (score 3):

Raw JS:

```
document.body.setAttribute('title', document.title);
```

In jQuery:

```
$(document.body).attr('title', $('head title').html());
```

Comment: document.title already holds the title string so no need for the `.innerHTML`, the jQuery method is `.attr()` `=]`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first two points, you can do:

```
title = $('title').html();
$('<h1>'+title+'</h1>').appendTo('body');
```

this will get the page title to a variable to later insert it in a `<h1>` element at the top of the page body.